Bug with mdframed
I want to use the example from this question.
I have modified this example and change the line innertopmargin=0pt to innertopmargin=10mm.
It causes a bug: see the pictures below.
Is there a way to fix this bug?
(If someone comes with a solution using tcolorbox, it's ok)
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\wavydecor{%
    \draw[decoration={coil,aspect=0.1,segment length=5pt,amplitude=0.8pt},decorate,line width=1.5pt,black]
      (O|-P) -- (O);
}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
innertopmargin=10mm,
innerbottommargin=0pt,
leftmargin=-10pt,
skipabove=.5\baselineskip,
skipbelow=.5\baselineskip,
singleextra={\wavydecor},
firstextra={\wavydecor},
secondextra={\wavydecor},
middleextra={\wavydecor}
]{wavysbar}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}


PS: it used to work with my old distribution from 2017; it does not work with my new distribution from 2024.

#edit:
When I \listfiles, I get:
 *File List*
 article.cls    2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
kvoptions.sty    2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
  xparse.sty    2024-05-08 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2024-05-27 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
zref-abspage.sty    2023-09-14 v2.35 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2023-09-14 v2.35 Module base for zref (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
needspace.sty    2010/09/12 v1.3d reserve vertical space
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2024/04/13 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for pdftex
mathcolor.ltx
    tikz.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
     pgf.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  pgfrcs.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2024/05/23 v1.4g Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2023/12/02 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pgfsys.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  xcolor.sty    2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
mathcolor.ltx
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  pgffor.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
md-frame-1.mdf    2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-1
  lipsum.sty    2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
l3keys2e.sty    2024-05-08 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  lipsum.ltd
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********


I don't have this behaviour with my 2024 TeX Live distribution. Can you add \listfiles in your preamble, then look at your .log file and paste in your edited post what you see under *File List* in the log? For me, it begins with article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class and ends with epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live. I have compiled with pdflatex.

Why is this tagged with tcolorbox when your example is not using tcolorbox? Also you should use tcolorbox instead of mdframed as the latter hasn't been updated for several years.

My mistake, i have tested with the value innertopmargin=10pt, (because the original code in the linked question was with innertopmargin=0pt,), not with innertopmargin=10mm,. After further test, I find that when I replacing 10mm by 9mm, or 9.25mm, or 9.99408mm the bug is gone. But if I replace the value with 9.99409mm, the bug is here. No idea :(.

mdframed is not maintained and seems to have quite a few bugs with a current LaTeX. You can do this with the borderline west key of tcolorbox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}

\newtcolorbox{wavysbar}
  {
    breakable,
    blanker,
    top=10mm,
    pad at break*=0mm,
    borderline west={0mm}{-9pt}%
      {
        decoration={coil,aspect=0.1,segment length=5pt,amplitude=0.8pt},
        decorate,
        line width=1.5pt,
        black,
      },
  }
\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}

Page 1

Page 2

Page 3

